# is recursive mutex lock?

Tags: c++, multithreading

I have a question about `mutex_lock`. My code does the following:

1. `RIL_startEventLoop` lock the mutex by `pthread_mutex_lock(&s_startupMutex)`;
2. Call the thread `eventLoop`;
3. `eventLoop` locks the mutex by `pthread_mutex_lock(&s_startupMutex)`;
4. `eventLoop` unlocks the mutex by `pthread_mutex_unlock(&s_startupMutex)`;
5. `RIL_startEventLoop` unlocks the mutex by `pthread_mutex_unlock(&s_startupMutex)`;

My understanding is the following (correct me if wrong):

1. Lock the mutex exclusively for this task. If the mutex is not available right now, it will sleep until it can get it.
2. The mutex must later on be released by the same task that acquired it. Recursive locking is not allowed.

Why can `eventLoop` lock same mutex that is not released by `RIL_startEventLoop`?

These 2 functions are in Ril.cpp:

```
RIL_startEventLoop(void) {
    int ret;
    pthread_attr_t attr;
#ifdef MTK_RIL
    RIL_startRILProxys();
#endif /* MTK_RIL */
    /* spin up eventLoop thread and wait for it to get started */
    s_started = 0;
    **pthread_mutex_lock(&s_startupMutex);**

    pthread_attr_init (&attr);
    pthread_attr_setdetachstate(&attr, PTHREAD_CREATE_DETACHED);
    ret = pthread_create(&s_tid_dispatch, &attr, **eventLoop**, NULL);

    while (s_started == 0) {
        pthread_cond_wait(&s_startupCond, &s_startupMutex);
    }

    **pthread_mutex_unlock(&s_startupMutex);**

    if (ret < 0) {
        LOGE("Failed to create dispatch thread errno:%d", errno);
        return;
    }
}


static void *
**eventLoop(void *param)** {
    int ret;
    int filedes[2];

    ril_event_init();

    **pthread_mutex_lock(&s_startupMutex);**

    s_started = 1;
    pthread_cond_broadcast(&s_startupCond);

    **pthread_mutex_unlock(&s_startupMutex);**

    ret = pipe(filedes);

    if (ret < 0) {
        LOGE("Error in pipe() errno:%d", errno);
        return NULL;
    }

    s_fdWakeupRead = filedes[0];
    s_fdWakeupWrite = filedes[1];

    fcntl(s_fdWakeupRead, F_SETFL, O_NONBLOCK);

    ril_event_set (&s_wakeupfd_event, s_fdWakeupRead, true,
                   processWakeupCallback, NULL);

    rilEventAddWakeup (&s_wakeupfd_event);

    // Only returns on error
    ril_event_loop();
    LOGE ("error in event_loop_base errno:%d", errno);

    return NULL;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the call to pthread_cond_wait() releases the mutex.

pthread_cond_wait() does this in an atomic fashion.

1. Release the mutex (It must already be acquired)
2. Suspend the thread until the condition is signalled
3. Acquires the mutex